# Where should I setup a Database connection in Struts 2 app?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, struts2

I am developing a small web application using struts 2. I want to setup a database connection when the web application starts. After that, I want that database connection object to be used in the the entire web application to update records in the database server.

Where should I include the database connection setup code in my struts2 web application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't setup a database connection on webapp startup. The DB will timeout the connection when it is been released for a too long time and that is truly shorter (~30 mins) than the time an average webapplication lives (days, months, years). Rather setup the datasource / DAO factory at that point. Connections are to be acquired and closed in the **shortest possible scope**. The normal JDBC idiom is the following:

```
public void create(Entity entity) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;

    try { 
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_CREATE);
        statement.setSomeObject(1, entity.getSomeProperty());
        // ...
        statement.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }
}
```

Note the closing in `finally`. It prevents leaking resources (i.e. not closing them) when an exception occurs.

To improve connecting performance you normally want to use a connection pool. Any decent appserver provides this facility in flavor of a JNDI datasource. In for example Tomcat, you can find in the [JNDI Resources HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) how to create one. This by the way does not mean that you don't need to close them, you **still** need to close them according the usual JDBC idiom. The connection pool namely returns a wrapped connection which does something like the following in the `close()`:

```
public void close() throws SQLException {
    if (this.connection is still eligible for reuse) {
        do not close this.connection, but just return it to pool for reuse;
    } else {
        actually invoke this.connection.close();
    }
}
```

As to setting up the datasource (or DAO factory) on webapp startup, there are several ways. One is using a [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) which does the task in the `contextInitialized()` method, another way is using a Struts2-managed application scoped bean which does the task in the constructor.

Also see this [basic JDBC/DAO tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) for more hints how to get started with JDBC (in webapplications) the proper way.